# Who can I contact to discuss adding features to Apple's operating systems?

Tags: macos, ios

I have some ideas (i.e. certain software algorithms) which I think could enhance the user experience if implemented in the next version of Apple's operating systems.

I'd like to connect with somebody from the company to discuss this in more detail.

I'm not sure where to start because I know I'm going to get nowhere talking to customer service.

Can anybody here point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are suggesting new features or enhancements, try:

http://www.apple.com/feedback/

If you are reporting bugs, try:

https://bugreport.apple.com/

If you need to discuss extensive changes or a new direction you believe Apple should take, I suspect you will have to apply for a job with the department you believe your ideas will have most value in, and then find those who make the design decisions, and convince them that your ideas are the best direction going forward.

Comment: I had a feeling i'd get downvoted a bit. thanks for the quick answer. It would be great if I could obtain an email address for one of these people who make design decisions...

Comment: @StevenLu I imagine it would.  Why don't you write a blog with your suggestions and try to get the community and other Apple enthusiasts excited about your ideas?  If they are great, others will see the value in them.

Comment: I think I have read somewhere that Apple generally does not accept ideas for new features or products from outside sources, because doing so might land them in legal trouble later on, when the originator of the idea might decide to sue for compensation. But as I do not remember the source, take this with a generous helping of salt. I throw this unreliable recollection out here in the hope that it will trigger others to either verify or refute it.

Comment: @StrevenLu  Your expectations about dialoguing with Apple are not realistic.   For more info  see  http://www.apple.com/legal/policies/ideas.html

Comment: Yes, I have found that policy and it's slightly frustrating. Still I'd like to see my idea implemented somehow so I'll see if I can't generate some interest by building a demo.

Comment: @StevenLu You might be better off talking to a JailBreak developer. If it's a good enough idea, and a lot of people like it, you can make some serious money, and Apple sometimes steals JailBreak ideas for use in the official releases of iOS.

Comment: I'm thinking about something related to core OS rendering functionality though. I'm not sure it'd be worth it to try to hack into these parts of the OS from "outside". I certainly don't have the know-how to get it right myself. It's quite applicable to other operating systems in general though, so long as the user interface allows for smooth scrolling motions. Maybe I'll try starting a conversation with Microsoft.

Comment: @StevenLu If you are keeping it secret for any reason, Apple will not even talk to you about it.  Post it on the internet and make it public.  Add a license indicating you are putting the idea in the public domain.  Get grass-roots user support for the feature and idea, and only then is it possible Apple will listen without becoming an employee.  Why don't you explain your idea here, and see what this community thinks of it?

Comment: Okay. I'm not really trying to get any money out of this, but if you're interested I'm happy to summarize it in a sentence or two. I was scrolling quickly through some documents on my iPad earlier today and noticed that while the animation is nice and smooth at 60Hz, there is still a significant "strobe-light" effect. I'd recently done some research (see here http://stevenlu.net/files/motion_blur_2d/Fragment_shader_dynamic_blur3.pdf) and a very simple GPU fragment shader program can be used to make any scrolling element look much better than it does now.

Comment: I think that blurring a quickly scrolling view element on the screen can enhance the quality as perceived by the user of the product. My powerpoint there describes how it can be applied in games to general 2d rigid body transformations but scrolling is quite a simple subset of that problem. What I want is for scrolling documents to look as nice as my little game prototypes. I'm more interested in the advancement of science and technology than me making a few bucks. That said if i'm the first to come up with the idea I'd like to receive some form of credit.

Comment: @StevenLu That's interesting.  I think you could write a sample app that shows the difference very clearly for scrolling a page of lorem ipsem text on an iOS device and on the mac.  If you can give people an app that demonstrates the utility of your discovery, they might bite.  Apple would have a problem with *"if i'm the first to come up with the idea I'd like to receive some form of credit."* though.  They'd rather see you patent it, prove that no one else has done so, then give the patent to them.